# Pandas: DataReader in combination with ISIN identification

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I'm trying to compute some portfolio statistics using Python Pandas, and I am looking for a way to query stock data with DataReader using the ISIN (International Securities Identification Number).

However, as far as I can see, DataReader is not compatible with such ids, although both YahooFinance and GoogleFinance can handle such queries.

How can I use DataReader with stock ISINs?

Comment: Have a look at this thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799442/using-python-get-download-daily-finance-market-data-stocks-etfs-etc-by-t

Comment: Have a look at this thead here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799442/using-python-get-download-daily-finance-market-data-stocks-etfs-etc-by-t

Answer (score -1):

If you have the ISIN, then you also have the the symbol, see the wikipedia page for information about how to translate ISIN to symbol: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number#ISIN_Calculation_Methodology

Write a little bit of python code to translate the ISIN back to the symbol, then use the usual DataReader query.

One last thing. From a quick perusal of google and yahoo finance websites, it's not clear what you mean when you say that both support queries with these ids. Searching on both sites with Apple's ISIN turns up very few results, and no quotes.

Comment: Hi Joan, thank you very much for your comment. I did not know that you could convert ISIN to Ticker Symbols. Do you know if there is a Python library which does the job of converting between the different ids?

Comment: A quick google doesn't turn anything up, but really, that's straightforward python code to write. Convert number to string, iterate over characters, add 55, convert to ascii, and slice off the check digit, and voila!

Comment: Hi Joan, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I had to find out that the ISIN code does not always consist exclusively of numbers after the country code (i.e.: DE000XNG8888) do you have an idea how to convert those strings? into stock symbols?

Comment: Are you always using the same set of ISIN's, but a few are consistently non-numeric? I'd probably just make a lookup table of the weird ones, and not worry too much, as long as the solution supported it.

Answer (score -1):

Forget about Python. There is absolutely no way to convert an ISIN to a Ticker Symbol. You have completely misunderstood the wikipedia page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).